# Authorization component URIs react and redux based on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, authorization, acl

I m beginner with **react-redux** and I want to implement authorization. Here is my container named **RestrictedRoute** that checks if targetted URI is allowed to the user or not. Now the issue is that default state isAllowed was check as false. when the component is rendered, the default isAllowed state was false value and render checks if isAllowed is false then redirect to **403** component. I want to trigger my action **checkComponent()** before render on each route change such that it will not false in allowed URIs from DB after API request on each route change

```
class RestrictedRoute extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           componentRoute:''
        }
       }
       componentWillMount() {
        const componentRoute = this.props.pathname;
        this.props.getUser();
        this.props.checkComponent(componentRoute);

      }

      componentDidMount() {
        if(this.state.componentRoute === ''){

          // const componentRoute = this.props.pathname;

        }else{

        }
        // console.log("restrictions");

      }
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        // console.log("prevProps", prevProps);
        // console.log("next props", this.props);
        if (this.props.pathname !== prevProps.pathname && this.pathname !== "/invalid_page") {
          // alert("hello");
          const componentRoute = this.props.pathname;
          this.props.getUser();
          // console.log(componentRoute);
          this.props.checkComponent(componentRoute);

        }
      }

      render() {
        const Component = this.props.component;
        // console.trace("restricted route allowed", this.props.rest);
        return (
          <Route 
          // {...this.props.rest} 
          render={
            (props) => {
              if (this.props.authUser===null) {
                return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
              } else {
                // alert("allowed", this.props.isAllowed);

                if(this.props.isAllowed || this.props.location.pathname==="/invalid_page"){

                return <Component {...props} />;
                }else{
                  // alert("usman hafeez");
                  return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/invalid_page', state: { from: props.location } }} />
                }
              }
            }
          } />
        )
      }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({
        checkComponent: checkComponent,
        getUser: getUser
      }, dispatch);
    }

    var mapStateToProps = ({ routing ,auth}, otherProps) => {
      // console.log("restricted route", routing);
      // console.log("restricted auth", auth);
      // console.log("restricted other", otherProps);
      return {
        // routing: routing,
        pathname: routing.location.pathname,
        authUser: auth.authUser,
        isAllowed: auth.isAllowed
      };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RestrictedRoute);
```

here is my **checkComponent** Action

```
export const checkComponent = (componentUri) => {
console.log("KSDJ")
return (dispatch) => {
// alert("hello");
RestService.checkComponent(componentUri).then((resp) => {

  if (RestService.checkAuth(resp.data)) {
    if (resp.data.status === true) {
      dispatch({
        type: COMPONENT_ALLOWED,
        payload: resp.data.ComponentAllowed
      });

    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: INVALID_RESPONSE
      });
    }
  } else {
    dispatch({
      type: INVALID_TOKEN
    });
  }
 });
 }
};
```

here is my auth.js reducer file

```
import {
 HIDE_MESSAGE,
 INIT_URL,
 ON_HIDE_LOADER,
 ON_SHOW_LOADER,
 SHOW_MESSAGE,
 LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
 LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS,
 LOGIN_FAILED,
 INVALID_TOKEN,
 COMPONENT_ALLOWED,
 ACCESS_DENIED,
 UPDATE_PROFILE,
 GET_USER
} from "constants/ActionTypes";
import RestService from '../services/RestServices';
import { message } from "antd";
     const INIT_STATE = {
  loader: false,
  alertMessage: '',
  showMessage: false,
  initURL: '',

  isAllowed: true,

  authUser: localStorage.getItem('authUser'),

};


export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  // console.log("auth.js");
  // console.log("states");
  // console.log("auth user state");
  // console.log(state.authUser);
  // console.log("actions");
  // console.log(action.type);

  switch (action.type) {

    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS: {
      // console.log("logged in");
      return {
        ...state,
        loader: false,
        authUser: action.payload
      }
    }
    case GET_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        authUser:{
          id: action.payload.id,
          connected_dealer: action.payload.connected_dealer,
          email: action.payload.email,
          dealerId: action.payload.dealerId,
          firstName: action.payload.firstName,
          lastName: action.payload.lastName,
          name: action.payload.name,
          type: action.payload.type,
          dealer_pin: action.payload.dealer_pin
        }
      }
    }
    case LOGIN_FAILED: {
      // console.log({
      //   ...state,
      //   alertMessage: action.payload.msg,
      //   showMessage: true,
      //   loader: false
      // });

      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: action.payload.msg,
        showMessage: true,
        loader: false
      }
    }
    case INIT_URL: {
      return {
        ...state,
        initURL: action.payload
      }
    }
    case LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        authUser: {
          id: null,
          connected_dealer: null,
          email: null,
          dealerId: null,
          firstName: null,
          lastName: null,
          name: null,
          token: null,
          type: null
        },
        initURL: '/',
        loader: false
      }
    }

    case UPDATE_PROFILE: {
      if (action.response.status) {
        message.success(action.response.msg);
        state.authUser.firstName = action.response.data.first_Name;
        state.authUser.lastName = action.response.data.Last_Name;
        localStorage.setItem('firstName', action.response.data.first_Name);
        localStorage.setItem('lastName', action.response.data.Last_Name);

        // console.log('user detail',action.response);
        // console.log('user state',state.authUser);

      }
      else {
        message.error(action.response.msg);
      }
      return {
        ...state,

        loader: false,

      }
    }
      break;

    case INVALID_TOKEN: {
      RestService.authLogOut();
      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: "Login expired",
        showMessage: true,
        authUser: {
          id: null,
          connected_dealer: null,
          email: null,
          dealerId: null,
          firstName: null,
          lastName: null,
          name: null,
          token: null,
          type: null
        },
        initURL: '/',
        loader: false
      }
    }
    case SHOW_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: action.payload,
        showMessage: true,
        loader: false
      }
    }
    case HIDE_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: '',
        showMessage: false,
        loader: false
      }
    }

    case ON_SHOW_LOADER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loader: true
      }
    }
    case ON_HIDE_LOADER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loader: false
      }
    }
    case COMPONENT_ALLOWED: {

      // console.log("dsfsdfsdf",action.payload)
      return {
        ...state,
        isAllowed: action.payload
      }
      break;
    }
    case ACCESS_DENIED: {
      return {
        ...state,
        initURL: '/invalid_page'
      }
      break;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

reducer combining index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { routerReducer } from "react-router-redux";
import Auth from "./Auth";

const reducers = combineReducers({

  auth: Auth,
});

export default reducers;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine.
Can you provide the checkComponent code? maybe the problem in the action itself.

Comment: auth reducer and combining reducer are also added

Comment: so, the default state of isAllowed is true, not false and this should redirect the users to the component, not the 403 component. the place where you call the action is right, I think to avoid the problem with showing the 403 component is to add loader that runs immediately after calling the checkComponent action then stop it in the response. Also, did you confirmed that isAllowed props come with the right value?

Comment: yes after action it comes with correct value, and first time it loaded with default value